# CALayer mask slows down view transitions iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, core-animation

Im using a CAShapeLayer mask to animate the drawing of circular progress bar:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, Nil, 99.65, 99.25, 84, radians(startAngle), radians(endAngle), 0);

CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.path = path;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
layer.lineWidth = 21;
layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
layer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
layer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

_progressBar.layer.mask = layer;

// Configure animation
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration            = ANIMATION_DURATION;
drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
[layer addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

The animation works great, the circular progress bar goes from empty to full smoothly. The problem is when I transition from this view once the progress animation has completed. When the next view slides in, or this view slides back in to view the segue transition animation is choppy.

I have narrowed the problem down to the mask '_progressBar.layer.mask = layer;'. When I remove it transitions are smooth again.

Setting layer.shouldRasterize = YES on the mask or image layer doesn't seem to help.

I'm not sure how to optimise this so segue transitions are smooth. Test device is iPhone 4.

**UPDATE**
Tested on iPhone 3GS: Smoother but not perfect, definitely better than 4!
Tested on iPhone 5: Smooth off course, this phone is very fast.

iPhone 4 seems to have problems with mask operations If anyone knows of a workaround would love to hear it.

Comment: Rasterizing the layer while animating it should even give you _worse_ performance.

Comment: I set rasterize in viewWillDisappear since the problem is the segue transition animation not the actual progress animation as it has finished at that point. I mentioned it because the progress animation needs the mask which seems to cause the problem. Updated q so its clearer.